# CSS loading delays page display

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I work on a wordpress website, and i saw that a css file take about 10 seconds to load, and delays the page display, so i'd like to know how i can make this loading much faster.

I have installed caching plugin, and i use visual composer plugin.
The visual composer's css file is causing the delay.

The header is like this:

```
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        ...
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='vc_plugin_themes_css-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-tables-vc/assets/css/themes.css?ver=4.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='js_composer_front-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.css?ver=4.7.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' id='ubermenu-css'  href='http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/pro/assets/css/ubermenu.min.css?ver=3.2.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
        ...
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
    </head>
```

Do you think i should move the js_composer.css in the footer? or there is something else i can do?

Regards

Comment: You move JS to the end of a page, not CSS. I can see that it's a [big file](https://vc.wpbakery.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/css/js_composer.min.css?ver=4.11). Though I don't think that's the issue you're facing. What kinds of things have you done to improve the delivery of your website and it's assets? Here's some [Optimization Tips](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules#speed-rules).

Comment: This is not the best way to load css and js in WordPress: See http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sites like gtmetrix.com, that will show you specifically what the problem is and what you can do to fix it. They are very informative and analytical. You may need to imply server changes or changes of your administrator page, but they totally work.